# Retornando Array externo ao pegar dados com Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Eu tenho uma coluna chamada `clube` e em uma linha dela tem o seguinte `{"clube":["Santos"]}`, usando essa forma para os dados

```
$clubes = Socios::where('socio', $socio)->select('clube')->get();
```

Ele me retorna desta forma `[{"clube":"{"clube":["Santos"]}"}]`, com um array externo chamado `clube`, como posso fazer para retornar apenas oque está dentro do campo no banco de dados ??

Comment: `clube` não é o nome do campo ??? e dentro do array é `clube` também? é só pegar o resultado `$clubes[0]->cluble` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar **[metodo pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck)** nativo do laravel, ficaria algo do tipo:

```
$clubes = Socios::where('socio', $socio)->pluck('clube');
```

se quiseres em forma de array basta adicionar **toArray()**:

```
$clubes = Socios::where('socio', $socio)->pluck('clube')->toArray();
```